# Perforce - find the most recently updated files in a branch

Tags: perforce

How can I order files by "most recently modified" or get a list of the most recently modified files in Perforce?

Comment: Do you want files within a certain time range (like all files modified this week), or do you want a certain number of file revisions ordered by submit time?

Comment: @Samwise submit time. Your answer works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is to start with `p4 changes` (which orders its output by most recent) and pipe the result into `p4 files`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -ztag -F @=%change% changes -m10 -ssubmitted | p4 -x - files
//stream/main/move/bar#1 - move/add change 276 (text)
//stream/main/move/foo#2 - move/delete change 276 (text)
//stream/main/move/foo#1 - add change 275 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/01.txt#3 - move/add change 274 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/02.txt#2 - move/delete change 274 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/01.txt#2 - move/delete change 273 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/legacy_01.txt#1 - move/add change 273 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/01.txt#3 - move/add change 272 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/02.txt#2 - move/delete change 272 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/01.txt#2 - move/delete change 271 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/legacy_01.txt#1 - move/add change 271 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/01.txt#3 - move/add change 269 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/02.txt#2 - move/delete change 269 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/01.txt#2 - move/delete change 268 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/legacy_01.txt#1 - move/add change 268 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/01.txt#1 - branch change 267 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/02.txt#1 - branch change 267 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/01.txt#1 - branch change 267 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/02.txt#1 - branch change 267 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/01.txt#1 - add change 266 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/02.txt#1 - add change 266 (text)
```

Note that the file revisions are ordered descending by change, because we got each batch via a `p4 files @=CHANGE` command.

Another approach if you just want "recently updated files" for some arbitrary value of "recent" is to do a simple `p4 files` command with a revision range, e.g. a date range:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 files @2021/07/30,now
//stream/main/main/A/01.txt#3 - move/add change 265 (text)
//stream/main/main/A/02.txt#2 - move/delete change 265 (text)
//stream/main/main/A/legacy_01.txt#1 - move/add change 264 (text)
//stream/main/main/B/01.txt#1 - branch change 263 (text)
//stream/main/main/B/02.txt#1 - branch change 263 (text)
//stream/main/move/bar#1 - move/add change 276 (text)
//stream/main/move/foo#2 - move/delete change 276 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/01.txt#3 - move/add change 269 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/02.txt#2 - move/delete change 269 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/A/legacy_01.txt#1 - move/add change 268 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/01.txt#3 - move/add change 274 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/02.txt#2 - move/delete change 274 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/B/legacy_01.txt#1 - move/add change 273 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/01.txt#3 - move/add change 272 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/02.txt#2 - move/delete change 272 (text)
//stream/main/seongchan-test/main/legacy_01.txt#1 - move/add change 271 (text)
```

In both cases, you can include a file specification to limit the results to a particular branch (e.g. add `//depot/my_branch/...` to the `p4 changes` command, or include it in the `@date,now` for the `p4 files` command).